# Ubuntu Serial Port Briefly showing on arduino IDE

Tags: serial, nodemcu, ubuntu

I am using a NodeMcu with Arduino IDE on Ubuntu.
I have managed to upload the blink script and it work.
Now, when i plug the nodemcu, the serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 is briefly available in the IDE.
After 2 seconds, the port menu is grayed out again and I can't use it.

Same with `ls /dev/tty*` `/dev/ttyUSB0` is briefly available.

```bash
/dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55      /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS30
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6       /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45  /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7       /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS23
/dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS24
/dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS25
```

After 2 seconds:

```bash
/dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55      /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS30
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6       /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45  /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7       /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22
/dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS23
/dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS24
/dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS25
```

How can I fix that? I have try all the usb ports.
The NodeMCU settings:
[image]

Actually Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

EDIT:
While running `sudo dmesg -w` and connecting the mcu I get:

```
[ 3726.038486] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 3726.220532] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 3726.220536] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3726.220537] usb 1-1: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 3726.220538] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 3726.220539] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 3726.229998] cp210x 1-1:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 3726.231005] usb 1-1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 3727.565688] usb 1-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 3727.566375] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 3727.566391] cp210x 1-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

Comment: the USB device here is the USB chip on the NodeMcu board, not the esp8266,

Comment: You may `tail -f /var/log/syslog` right before plugging in the board, and see if anything interesting shows up.

Comment: `sudo dmesg -w` will show you what's going on. Maybe it's shutting down the port because it's drawing too much current?

Comment: I have edited the post with result of the command.

Comment: From these logs, it looks like the [brltty](https://brltty.app/) daemon tried to mess with the serial port. Can you disable this daemon and try again?

Comment: I had this same problem and eventually I traced it down to two bad cables. It would appear, up then the port would disappear or change so the serial monitor would fault. Try several cables, it is the easiest solution if it is the problem. I generally do not unplug the cable from the Arduino, just the USB one and leave cables on each of the Arduino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be happening because `Brltty` application. Remove it and try again.

```
sudo apt remove brltty
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: brother you don't know you just saved my life 
for the last 2 days i was looking for this

Comment: I'm glad about it...